# IMPORTXML not working

Tags: google-sheets, importxml

I’m trying to scrap prices from various e-commerce site. However the IMPOrtxml function is not working

For instance,

https://shopee.sg/Ice-Silk-2019-Men-Underwear-Cool-Breathable-Comfortable-Sport-Bamboo-Fiber-Boxer-Stretchable-Brief-i.15618985.2902337324

Answer (score 0):

It seems the page content can not be parsed.

```
=IMPORTXML("https://shopee.sg/Ice-Silk-2019-Men-Underwear-Cool-Breathable-Comfortable-Sport-Bamboo-Fiber-Boxer-Stretchable-Brief-i.15618985.2902337324","//")
```

returns `#N/A`

I'm using the Chrome extension https://github.com/maximelebreton/quick-javascript-switcher to switch off the JS and check what data are still on the page. We can grab only that data.

Comment: So theres no way to scrap the data off? im grabing the price